# CSV / Spaces / and Macros

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm not sure if there's a solution to this or not. When I export a document to CSV (this is the only option) it adds a hidden space behind everything. I've figured out if I copy the space I can press CTRL + h paste the space in the find and then replace all will remove all the spaces. The problem: I'm working on a Macro and I'm not sure how to add this to the Macro or if it's even possible. My first thought was to record the action but when I do that and try to run it the space in the cell I chose gets deleted plus any manually typed spaces but the hidden spaces stay. Because of this I've had to make the Macro a two part Macro. Is there a way to delete those hidden spaces within the Macro or am I stuck copying the space and replacing it.

I tried to record the Macro knowing recordings have limited actions but I'm trying to build it into a Macro.

Below is what the data looks like exported. The #Value! is from a formula =today()-(Projected Return date)

When exporting to CSV from Chrome a Space is added at the end of each cell so the formula sees =today()-(13 Dec 23 )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijWFU.png)

I can copy the space after the 23 and replace and find and delete all the spaces without deleting manually typed spaces.

Copy space:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwz8v.png)

Replace all by pasting the Space in the find all:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX2RM.png)

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW5eI.png)

If I try to do it with a recorded Macro the Macro will delete all spaces but keep the odd space in the back:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk6vo.png)

Here's the Macro:

' Delete hidden spaces

`Range("L3").Select`
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "13 Dec 2023 "`
`Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _`
`xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _`
`FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2`

Comment: CSV and macros and documents in what context? What systems, environments, programs and languages are you working with?

Comment: Also please give us more details about this "hidden space"... How did you notice it if it's hidden? Do you know exactly what this space is, have you looked at the file in a hex-editor for example? Are you sure this space isn't in the original document?

Comment: Hopefully this helps cause I don't know to much about all this. We export the document from chrome or edge into a "microsoft excel comma separated values file" the only options are CSV or CSV Raw we use to have export to Excel but that's gone away. I noticed the hidden spaces when trying to do a formula trying to find days such as =today()-(chosen cell) and I was receiving #VALUE!. I knew I did the formula correct and the cell chosen was in date format. I went to google and saw someone else having the same problem and provided the replace solution.

Comment: The spaces get added to the end of each cell

Comment: First: I suggest editing your question to provide more detail, rather than putting details in comments. Second: I think you should add a real-world example of what the CSV data looks like. You should probably consider some type of data-cleansing step that takes care of unwanted characters causing your macros issues. Lastly: if you need help with your macros, then you should include the macro code in your question (along with the sample data, expected behavior, actual behavior, etc). There are just too many unknowns right now. Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidMakogon made and edit to the post to show examples hope that helps